# Add Facebook Pixel code

Tags: magento2, facebook

I am trying to add Facebook Pixel to my Magento2 Store,

I added the Pixel code to the header, but can't find a way to add the event tracking code after `<body>` in selected pages (Exemple: in checkout page for Purchase tracker)

I added all the tracking code in the header (inside the Pixel code) but it gives incorrect results since all pages will be tracked for selected events

```
<script>
  fbq('track', 'PageView');
  fbq('track', 'Purchase');
  fbq('track', 'Lead');
  fbq('track', 'CompleteRegistration');
  fbq('track', 'AddToCart');
  fbq('track', 'InitiateCheckout');
  fbq('track', 'ViewContent');    
</script>
```

Comment: You can try this: https://magenticians.com/add-facebook-pixel-magento-2/

Comment: You can search the "facebook pixel" on https://marketplace.magento.com and you find many extensions.

Answer (score 1):

The Simplest way to add this facebook pixel code is to Download the ready made Module and Use.

For ex:

> You have Apptrian Extensions - [Click Here](https://magenticians.com/add-facebook-pixel-magento-2/)

Or

> You have BSS Commerce Extensions - [Click Here](https://bsscommerce.com/magento-2-facebook-pixel-extension.html)

**Please check, Hope this will solve your problem.**

Answer (score 1):

you can try using this module available on git

https://github.com/Magento-Garage/m2-facebook-pixel